# Set text size of JComboBox in Swing

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jcombobox, font-size

I have created a combo-box in java (using Netbeans). I want to set the text size of each item in the list but don't know how to do it. (Preferably I want to use the default font style).
Any idea anyone how to do it?

Code Snippet:

```
private javax.swing.JComboBox ComboBox_agent = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
ComboBox_agent.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "TCP", "UDP", "Sink", "NULL" }));
```

Comment: did you try with `setFont` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you created the `JComboBox` in Netbeans GUI editor, there is a field for "Font" that allows you to change the size.

Answer (score 4):

Use a list cell rendering component with an appropriate font size.  This example uses 20 pixels.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class ShowFonts {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.
                    getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            String[] fonts = ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
            JComboBox fontChooser = new JComboBox(fonts);
            fontChooser.setRenderer(new FontCellRenderer());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fontChooser);
        });
    }
}

class FontCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
        JList list,
        Object value,
        int index,
        boolean isSelected,
        boolean cellHasFocus) {
        JLabel label = (JLabel)super.getListCellRendererComponent(
            list,value,index,isSelected,cellHasFocus);
        Font font = new Font((String)value, Font.PLAIN, 20);
        label.setFont(font);
        return label;
    }
}
```